# IBM Worklight - Blackberry App not working in OS 6.0 or 7.1

Tags: blackberry, ibm-mobilefirst, ripple

Blackberry app working in OS 5.0 but not working in OS 6.0 or 7.1

Following steps I follow in ripple:

1. Selected platform webworks 2.0.0
2. In Build option clicked on settings and entered new SDK path.
3. Entered native folders path in Project Root
4. gave a name in Archive name
5. entered a path in output folder
6. ENtered password in password field

still getting error while packaging "CreateProcessW: The system cannot find the file specified."
So still packaging the app manually and the app is working in OS 5.0 but not in OS

I have used Worklight 5.0.6.2 and 5.0.5 to develop app and in both the case the app is working only in OS 5.0

Using:

- Worklight 5.0.5/5.0.6.2
- BlackBerry SDK v2.3.1.5
- "BlackBerry" platform in Ripple

Comment: It sounds more like the whole app is not working rather than the adapter requests... it would be easier to help you fix the Ripple issue - edit your question with the issue and the Ripple version you're using.

Comment: Ripple Emulator (Beta) 0.9.16 and the error it shows me is "Oh Snap! Build request failed with message: CreateProcessW: The system cannot find the file specified." I tried changing my jdk version also but still it gives me the same error when i try to package my app

Answer (score 0):

The reason it works in the Ripple emulator is because all that emulator does is load the web resources of the application, which essentially is just like previewing the application using Worklight Console instead.

I am guessing that the following may help (it helped me get Ripple back into working condition):

1. Copy the BlackBerry SDK from Program files to C:\ (also remove any spaces in the folders path)
2. Make sure your Java is also in C:\
3. Navigate to the bin\ folder of the SDK in its new location
4. Open the file bbwp.properties file and edit the Java path to its new location in C:\
5. Check if Ripple now signs your application

In addition to the above, make sure that the "platform" you've chosen is "WebWorks 2.0.0". That's the correct platform when using BlackBerry 6/7.

In the Settings window in Ripple, you need to:

- point to the new SDK location from above.
- The path field needs to point to the native folder of your Worklight's BlackBerry environment.
- And of course you need to specify output folder location, name, signing keys password, ...

Try to package and sign again using Ripple.

I do hope of course, that you've read the Getting Started training material about BlackBerry?

- [Setting up your BlackBerry 6 and 7 development environment](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/01_04_Setting_up_your_BlackBerry_6_and_7_development_environment.pdf)
- [Previewing your application on BlackBerry 6 and 7](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/02_04_Previewing_your_application_on_BlackBerry_6_and_7.pdf)
- [General information when developing for BlackBerry 6 and 7](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/03_08_General_information_when_developing_for_BlackBerry_6_and_7.pdf)

Comment: Running zip in D:\WLStudio_5.0.5wrkspace\BBProject\apps\BBApp\blackberry\native
exec - "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Ext
ensions\cnijnnaimeaacneklcndcafbnkeicckh\0.9.16_0\services\node\node_modules\rbd
/../../../bin/zip.exe" -r "D:\mybbapp\Delete/firstApp.zip" *
error: CreateProcessW: The system cannot find the file specified.

error response - {"code":1,"msg":"CreateProcessW: The system cannot find the fil
e specified.\r\n","data":null}
2013-06-05 15:21:36 GET /ripple/build_status/456 200

Comment: made the changes you said still getting error while packaging and above is the error from the command prompt

Comment: See here: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Ripple-Error-Oh-Snap-Build-request-failed-with-message/td-p/1517861

Are you trying to build an application for bb10 or bb6/7? which sdk did you install? did you choose the correct platform in ripple?

Comment: the following is my sdk "BlackBerry WebWorks SDK 2.3.1.5" and the platform in ripple is "WebWorks" and i have declared " %SystemRoot%/system32 and %SystemRoot%" in my path. I had visited the following post before but still i'm getting error

Comment: why do you have all of those in your path?

Comment: do you have any idea about which all BB OS version worklight supports

Comment: Worklight supports BlackBerry OS 6, 7, 7.1 and 10.

Comment: Since you did not explain in your question what steps you took after my answer, I do not know why it works for you in 5 and not in 7.1

Comment: i didnt make any changes to my code what i did was i just tried installing the app on device with OS 5 and it worked but the same app when i am installing on device with os 7.1 its is not connecting to the server

Comment: Try with Worklight 5.0.6.1.

Comment: I developed a app in worklight 5.0.6.2 and this time also the app is connecting to the server in BB OS 5.0 but not working in BB OS 6.0

Comment: Did you follow my steps or yours? Please edit your question with the steps you've taken to create and run the app in BlackBerry OS 7.1.

Comment: I am asking for the steps you do IN RIPPLE.